# Whats "infix" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, infix-notation

I have seen Haskell code like this:

```
infix 4 ~=
(~=) :: Double -> Double -> Bool
x ~= y = abs (x-y) < epsilon
    where epsilon = 1 / 1000
```

Despite that I know what this code is doing, I would like to know what `infix 4` means.

Answer (score 6):

That is a [fixity declaration](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-820004.4.2):

> A fixity declaration gives the fixity and binding precedence of one or more operators.

In particular the `infix` part of `infix 4 ~=` means that the operator `~=` is not right or left associative, so `x ~= y ~= z` is not a valid expression.

And the precedence is 4 which means that it binds tighter than for example `&&`, so `x ~= y && z` parses as `(x ~= y) && z`, but less tight than for example `++`, so `x ~= y ++ z` parses as `x ~= (y ++ z)` (but that fails to type check). In that respect it is the same as comparison operators like `==`, so also `x == y ~= z` will give a parse error.

Here is a table of the fixities of standard operators (from the Haskell 2010 report linked above):

| Precedence | Left associative | Non-associative | Right associative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | !! |  | . |
| 8 |  |  | ^ , ^^ , ** |
| 7 | *, /, ‘div‘, ‘mod‘, ‘rem‘, ‘quot‘ |  |  |
| 6 | +, - |  |  |
| 5 |  |  | :, ++ |
| 4 |  | ==, /=, <, <=, >, >=, ‘elem‘, ‘notElem‘ |  |
| 3 |  |  | && |
| 2 |  |  | || |
| 1 | >>, >>= |  |  |
| 0 |  |  | $, $!, ‘seq‘ |

Comment: but how do i have to know that the number "4" indicates that? I mean is there a list or something which shows the order of diferent operators or something like that? I mean if now i see i code with infix 3 what is changing?

Comment: @j.j.3 You can find the fixity of an operator in ghci. If you run `:info ++`, you can see `infixr 5 ++`, so it has fixity 5. 5 is greater than 4, so it binds tighter. If you run `:info &&`, you can see `infixr 3 &&`. 3 is less than 4, so it binds looser.

Comment: The link at the start of my answer has a table with the standard operators. To compare with other operators you can look up the operator on hoogle and click through to the haddock documentation which will list the fixity. E.g. [`(.~) :: ASetter s t a b -> b -> s -> t   | infixr 4 |`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.2/docs/Control-Lens-Operators.html#v:.-126-)